# How to specify location of some nodes and let the rest be compute with some algorithm?

Tags: r, graph, igraph

I am trying to place some nodes at specific locations (the corners) and let the rest be placed by some algorithm.

I found [merge_coords](https://igraph.org/r/doc/merge_coords.html), but cannot figure it out and would be glad for a tip or code I could adapt. I cannot find any examples online, and the documentation has no examples I can draw from.

Here is the graph I am experimenting on:

```
# some graph (similar to my problem)
a <- matrix(0,10,10)
for(i in 1:10){
    a[i,] <- c(rep(0, 4),sample(c(0,1), 6, replace = T))
}
a[2,] <- c(rep(0, 4),sample(c(0,1), 6, replace = T))
a[3,] <- c(rep(0, 4),sample(c(0,1), 6, replace = T))
a[4,] <- c(rep(0, 4),sample(c(0,1), 6, replace = T))
colnames(a) <-  c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j")
g <- igraph::graph_from_adjacency_matrix(a,
                                         mode = "undirected",
                                         add.colnames = NULL)
attribute <- c(rep("special", 4),
               rep("nonspecial", 6))

g <- igraph::set_vertex_attr(g, "attA", value = attribute)
# viz
GGally::ggnet2(g,
               label = TRUE,
               mode = layout_(g, as_tree(root = V(g)[1:4]))
)
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Note: This was cross-posted to and answered at [the igraph forum](https://igraph.discourse.group/t/how-would-one-go-about-separating-nodes-into-areas-of-the-canvas-given-their-discrete-attribute/1573/2).